# Division resulting in incorrect result in Python

Tags: python, division

I am trying to divide a number in Python. However, it is giving me incorrect results.

For e.g., the below code

```
a= 559772387
a=a*a
print (int(a/2))
```

Expected Result- `156672562623838884`

Actual Result- `156672562623838880`

Can someone please explain if there is an issue with my understanding?

Comment: The division `/` returns a float result. Float arithmetic is imprecise. Try integer division `//` instead.

Comment: I tried in jupyter notebook, and getting the desired output. What env/kernel are you using?

Comment: I am using online compilers like that from HackerRank and CodeChef - https://www.codechef.com/ide

Comment: @MichaelButscher - Thanks, Chief, using // worked. I wasn't aware of this operator.